# Expanded column From List.Dates contracts after a subsequent merge

Tags: powerquery

My data has invoiced rental with a start date and end date, which more often than not overlaps our fiscal periods. I used the function List.Dates to create records for each date between the start and end dates, which worked great. When trying to merge the data to get the fiscal periods for each new record, I lose all the listed dates except for the first one.  Here is the advanced editor info:

```
let
    Source = Covid19,
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"DTTRANS", "NOPRODUIT", "DSLIGNE", "QTEXP", "PXVENDANT", "MTLIGNE", "DTDEB", "DTFIN", "Location", "Tableau1.Nocardex"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"NoCardex", "COMLOC", "Facture", "JoursAjustés", "DateDébut", "DateFin", "ParJour"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reordered Columns", {"NoCardex", "COMLOC", "Facture", "JoursAjustés", "DateDébut", "DateFin"}, {{"LocationParJour", each List.Sum([ParJour]), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Journee", each List.Dates([DateDébut],[JoursAjustés],#duration(1, 0, 0, 0))),
    #"Expanded {0}" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Journee"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded {0}",{{"Journee", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"JoursAjustés", "DateDébut", "DateFin"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns1", {"Journee"}, PériodesFiscales, {"DateTrans"}, "PériodesFiscales", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded {0}1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "PériodesFiscales", {"Produit"}, {"PériodesFiscales.Produit"})
in
    #"Expanded {0}1"
```

I am puzzled as to why I lose the dates. I am sure it is triviial. Hoping someone can help me figure this one out

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a bit embarrassing. I found out it had nothing to do with the expanded List.Dates. The merge changed the order of records. I found out after pasting a 1000 records onto a spreasheet to recreate the merge in Power Query without the expanded List.Dates. Turns out that the merge changed the sort on the orignal record set. Sorry. :-)

Comment: I would be interested to know how and why M is rearranging data.

Comment: Far from being an expert in this, I would say, given that most records were somewhat duplicated after the expansion of the List.Dates function, the susequent merge (based on the dates that werel isted) created some kind of index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is interesting and also a bit worrying not to understand why. Equally, when I merge my rows get duplicated and I then add another step to supress the duplicates. I wonder if I could prevent that in M code, not to have duplicates in the first place.

Comment: Hi, I need to clarify: the duplication of the records was done with the List.Dates function, as one record had for instance rental from march 25ht to April 6, I listed each dates in order to calculate the rental per fiscal periods. Before the merge, the records with the listed dates were together, then the merge re-ordered these records. Hoping this clarifies the matter.

Comment: OK! Indeed, it strongly clarifies!